# How can I check if Skype is running and there's an active call taking place?

Tags: windows, backup, automation, files, skype

How can I check if Skype is running **and** there's an active call taking place?
I need this to shut down Skype before making automatic backup (otherwise files are locked on exFAT so I can't make backup) but only if I don't break an active call.

Platform is Windows Vista.

Answer (score 2):

You can communicate with Skype through their API.  They have a variety of methods of doing this - including COM, Java, and Python - the ["kick start guide"](https://developer.skype.com/GettingStarted/KickStartGuide) is a good place to start reading (and there's a link to the API tracer, where you can basically interactively work with Skype via text commands).

A very rough way to do it would be to do a "SEARCH CALLS", then run through each call and check what the current status is.  I only looked at the [API](https://developer.skype.com/Docs/ApiDoc) for a couple of minutes, so a more thorough look would probably get a more efficient method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know Skype API tracer but I don't see a way how to get information out of it from command line. I don't want to engage in writing anything by myself just to get this simple thing working. They should really make Skype controllable from command line in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

For any other arriving here, the `SEARCH ACTIVECALLS` Skype command does exactly that.